# Ionic hide footer on one view

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-hide

I am trying to hide the footer on only one of my ionic views, no matter what I try I cannot seem to get this to work. Any ideas? I have tried using ng-hide and did not work. I can't seem to work out what the issue is. I will attach the code for the view and also the index where the footer is called from.

**Launchpad.html**

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">

  <ion-content class="padding uaContent">
    <search-results></search-results>

    <div ng-hide="query">
      <h2 class="card headingCard text-center padding">What do you want to do?</h2>
      <br>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <a ng-click="navToPlaylist()">
              <img src="img/myfavorites.png" width="65.6%" height="100%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a ng-click="navToSchedule()">
              <img src="img/program.png" width="32.8%" height="100%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <a href="#/menu/guide">
              <img src="img/interactive.png" width="65.6%" height="100%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a ng-click="navToExhibitors()">
              <img src="img/exhibitors.png" width="32.8%" height="100%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <a href="#/menu/smart">
              <img src="img/smartposters.png" width="32.5%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a href="#/menu/badges">
              <img src="img/mybadges.png" width="32.5%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a href="#/menu/menti">
              <img src="img/interact.png" width="32.5%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col>
            <a ng-click="navToInfo()">
              <img src="img/information.png" width="32.5%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a ng-click="navToAbout()">
              <img src="img/about.png" width="32.5%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col>
            <a href="#/menu/newsfeed">
              <img src="img/twitter.png" width="32.5%">
            </a>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>

    </div>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**index.html**

```
<ion-footer-bar>
      <div class="tabs tabs-positive" ng-controller="NavController" style="left: 0">
        <a id="menuTab" class="tab-item navTab schedTab activeTab"  href="#/menu/launchpad">
          <i class="icon ion-ios-home"></i>
        </a>
        <a id="guideTab" class="tab-item navTab guideTab activeTab" ng-click="navToGuide()">
          <i class="icon icon-street-view"></i>
        </a>
        <a id="arTab" class="tab-item navTab arTab activeTab" ng-click="navToAr()">
          <i class="icon ion-camera"></i>
        </a>
        <a id="schedTab" class="tab-item navTab menuTab activeTab" ng-click="navToPlaylist()">
          <i class="icon ion-heart"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: where you used ng-hide in above footer code ?

Comment: @CodeChanger I had it for the full ion-footer-bar. Is there a better solution to this? I can't get it to hide to matter what I try